# How to use Watir for web app testing on Java?

Tags: java, ruby, eclipse, watir, watir-webdriver

I've been assigned by our prof as the QA tester of our thesis web application and he wanted me to use Watir for testing the web application. But, I'm currently split as to how I'm supposed to approach this.

I know Watir is using Ruby as it's main language, so should I study Ruby first?(I only have experience on Java, C++, and a little bit of Scala so far.) Or should I go straight to the documentations?

We're using Eclipse as our default terminal for the web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to know Ruby to work in WATIR, but it's very easy language, more closely put, it's syntax is neat and clean. And also WATIR is very easy to use and having very lesser code compared to selenium,  I write code below using both WATIR and Selenium so that you could see the difference.

To select a select_list in WATIR, you need to write the following code

```
b.select_list(:id,'country').select 'India'
```

The same equivalent in Selenium

```
element=driver.findElement(By.id("country");
Select var=new Select(element);
var.selectByVisibleText("India");
```

So you might have understand the difficulty level when you write code in Java using selenium.

Ruby has a very rich Library so most of the functions would be readily available to you which you don't have code from your level.

Comment: Thanks for comparison, I guess I just need to dive into the API.

Comment: @KeithYung Yes, you need to!

Answer (score 0):

This question is ill-suited for SO because it will yield opinion-based answers.  But I can't help doing some `watir` cheerleading:

Consider this example from https://github.com/watir/watir:

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'google.com'
browser.text_field(title: 'Search').set 'Hello World!'
browser.button(type: 'submit').click

puts browser.title
# => 'Hello World! - Google Search'
browser.close
```

There are a bunch of programming concepts here: requiring external libraries, instantiating an object, local variables, symbol-based locators, method-chaining, printing to console, etc.

But who cares?  It's fairly clear that the script is creating a browser and going to google to perform a search.

So dive in and start writing `watir` code and refer to the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/frames)--`watir`or `ruby`--when you get stuck or need clarification.